# C++ Merge Sort Algorithm for use with arrays of variable size

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, mergesort

I've been having trouble, after spending hours of searching online on how to do Merge Sort and following  an algorithm I found, I got this, which produces a stack overflow error that I can't seem to trace

```
template <class T>
void mergeSort(T list[], int lowerBound, int upperBound)
{
    int mid;

    if (upperBound > 1)
    {
        mid = ( 1 + upperBound) / 2;
        mergeSort(list, lowerBound, mid);    
        mergeSort(list, lowerBound + 1, upperBound);
        merge(list, lowerBound, upperBound, mid);
    }
}

template <class T>
void merge(T list[], int lowerBound, int upperBound, int mid)
{
    int* leftArray = NULL;    
    int* rightArray = NULL;     
    int i, j, k;    
    int n1 = mid - lowerBound + 1;
    int n2 = upperBound - mid;    
    leftArray = new int[n1];    
    rightArray = new int[n2];       
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        leftArray[i] = list[lowerBound + i];    
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        rightArray[j] = list[mid + 1 + j];

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = lowerBound;

    while (i < n1 && j < n2)
    {
        if (leftArray[i] <= rightArray[j])
        {
            list[k] = leftArray[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            list[k] = rightArray[j];
            j++;
        }

        k++;
    }

    while (i < n1)
    {
        list[k] = leftArray[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while (j < n2)
    {
        list[k] = rightArray[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }

    delete [] leftArray;  
    delete [] rightArray;
}
```

When originally called, the lower bound is 1, the array is of type T holding ints, and the upper bound is a user determined size

EDIT: After some edits made based off the comments, this is what I have, however elements aren't being sorted.

```
template <class T>
void mergeSort(T list[], int lowerBound, int upperBound)
{
    int mid;

    if (upperBound > lowerBound)
    {
        mid = (lowerBound + upperBound) / 2;

        mergeSort(list, lowerBound, mid);

        mergeSort(list, mid + 1, upperBound);

        merge(list, lowerBound, upperBound, mid);
    }
}

template <class T>
void merge(T list[], int lowerBound, int upperBound, int mid)
{
    int* leftArray = NULL;

    int* rightArray = NULL;

    int i, j, k;

    int n1 = mid - lowerBound + 1;

    int n2 = upperBound - mid;

    leftArray = new int[n1];

    rightArray = new int[n2];

    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        leftArray[i] = list[lowerBound + i];

    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        rightArray[j] = list[mid + 1 + j];

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = lowerBound;

    while (i < n1 && j < n2)
    {
        if (leftArray[i] <= rightArray[j])
        {
            list[k] = leftArray[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            list[k] = rightArray[j];
            j++;
        }

        k++;
    }

    while (i < n1)
    {
        list[k] = leftArray[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while (j < n2)
    {
        list[k] = rightArray[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }

    delete [] leftArray;

    delete [] rightArray;
}
```

Comment: What have you done to debug? Have you checked that your for/while loops always stay in bounds?

Comment: in your function `mergesort`, the `if` condition according to me shall be `if(upperbound>lowerbound)`

Comment: I was using break points within the functions and none of them even hit EDIT: fixed the if statement, but elements aren't getting sorted

Comment: further you make a recursive call to `mergeSort(list, lowerBound + 1, upperBound);` shouldn't it be `mergeSort(list, mid + 1, upperBound);` and moreover why is `mid=(1+upperbound)/2` shouldn't it be `mid=(lowerbound+upperbound)/2`. Please explain if u believe I am saying anything that fails your logic.

Comment: Is there a reason `std::` functions are a no-go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okkk.. So, after all the changes made by you from the comments, the only problem I believe is the `mergesort` call from the main function.
I believe your mergesort call looked something like this `mergeSort(list,1,5)` (for an array of size 5).
Try changing it to `mergeSort(list,0,4)`

So, now your code shall look something like this::

```
void mergeSort(int list[], int lowerBound, int upperBound)
{
    int mid;

    if (upperBound > lowerBound)
    {
        mid = ( lowerBound + upperBound) / 2;
        mergeSort(list, lowerBound, mid);
        mergeSort(list, mid + 1, upperBound);
        merge(list, lowerBound, upperBound, mid);
    }
}
void merge(int list[], int lowerBound, int upperBound, int mid)
{
    int* leftArray = NULL;
    int* rightArray = NULL;
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = mid - lowerBound + 1;
    int n2 = upperBound - mid;
    leftArray = new int[n1];
    rightArray = new int[n2];
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        leftArray[i] = list[lowerBound + i];
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        rightArray[j] = list[mid + 1 + j];

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = lowerBound;

    while (i < n1 && j < n2)
    {
        if (leftArray[i] <= rightArray[j])
        {
            list[k] = leftArray[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            list[k] = rightArray[j];
            j++;
        }

        k++;
    }

    while (i < n1)
    {
        list[k] = leftArray[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while (j < n2)
    {
        list[k] = rightArray[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }

    delete [] leftArray;
    delete [] rightArray;
}
```

And the `main` shall look something like this::

```
int main(void) {
    int a[]={7,4,2,19,5};
    int i;
    mergeSort(a,0,4);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I just removed the `template` part because I wasn't much familiar with it. But, I don't think that will make much of a difference.

This is the ideone link to the execution of your code:: http://ideone.com/40wFkI

It seems to work fine to me. If there's anything wrong do let me know.

Hope this helps. :)